# Pandas - filtering data sets and combining them

Tags: python, pandas

I am filtering ancestry from the ABS in Australia.
I am taking ancestry data as below.

```
allvic_url='ABS_CENSUS2011_T09/TOT+1+2+3+4+Z.TOT+TOTP+1101+1102+6101+3204+2303+2101+5201+2305+2306+3205+3304+7106+2201+3103+6902+4106+3206+3104+1201+1202+3307+3308+2102+3213+7115+9215+3106+4907+5107+2103+OTH+Z.2.SA2..A/all?detail=Full&dimensionAtObservation=AllDimensions'
```

I am then having issues showing the changes in ancestry over time by using the newer 2016 dataset, as the api is extremely confusing... here http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/# . (I want to try and show how demographics are changing in suburbs as a datapoint).

The output I am aiming for is a dataframe on a suburb level that shows ancestry changes over time. If the api can give me more historical data on top of this that would be brilliant as well.

```
Suburb  Ancestry Main   Ancestry Secondary  Ancestry increased most Percentage increase 2016-2011
```

(i.e., showing the ancestry average is chinese, adn has changed x% over time).

Would appreciate help on solving this issue - Thanks!

Comment: It's good that you provide code examples. But hey are not just reproducible (copy and paste) and contain more details distracting from the problem. I would suggest to focus on a minimal example with hard-coded values as input examples, what you are getting out and what you actually would want to get out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As @de1 already wrote. Please add a [mcve](/help/mcve) and in particular the expected output.

Comment: Will do - will come back on later on tonight and update answer

Comment: You seem to be asking several questions about several problems. My strong suggestion is that you break these up into different questions. For example, if you provide detail on, "When trying to create a new column for the restaurants and other venues like movie theatres that has a count per suburb, I am getting errors when trying to use Regex to filter the venue categories with Restaurant." -- That's a problem I can help with. Break up this question into several and you're more likely to get answers.

Comment: Fair point - I have been fiddling for awhile so just was frustrated, I'll change the question to be more specific

Comment: From the question as stated, in addition to the comments above, it is not clear if you received specific errors at various points and/or you are hoping to have SO as a coding service.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Let me just focus down what I'm asking for. I am just trying to get filtering working, have tried a lot of different aproaches, just seems to not work thuogh

Comment: Hi could you please create a simple copy paste example of your data, like 5-10 rows and what you would expect as an output from there (also as an copy paste table)? It is much easier to understand what you want with data we can directly work with.

Comment: Hey, @Michael Holborn, It seems very interesting! Please, provide some data to try to help you :) ("Minimal Viable Example" means you provide an example, with code and/or data, not just description).

Comment: I think the best way we can help you is if you share a small portion of your code with the specific problem you have. Right now it's too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (at least part of) the question you're asking is how to filter a pandas dataframe using regex. For data I used some of the venue values you provided in your array. For your use case, this would be done as follows:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

df_with_venues = DataFrame(
    {
        "Venue Category": [
            "Speakeasy",
            "Boutique",
            "Peruvian Restaurant",
            "Bakery",
            "Vietnamese Restaurant",
            "Asian Restaurant",
            "Hotel",
            "Whisky Bar",
            "Street Art",
            "Italian Restaurant",
            "Bookstore",
            "French Restaurant",
            "Café",
            "Sushi Restaurant",
            "Australian Restaurant",
            "Indian Restaurant",
            "Coffee Shop",
            "Bar",
            "Wine Bar",
            "Theater",
            "BBQ Joint",
            "Burger Joint",
        ]
    }
)

regex_filter_venues = df_with_venues[df_with_venues["Venue Category"].str.match(r".*Restaurant")]
```

You specified in your question that you wanted restaurant so I provided that in this solution, but you should be able to replace the string, ".*Restaurant", with any valid regex. Also for reference if anyone wants it, the documentation for pandas regex is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) and there's also a great tutorial on different ways you can use pandas regex [here](https://kanoki.org/2019/11/12/how-to-use-regex-in-pandas/)

Comment: For reference, this is the answer to part of the originally posted question, which the OP changed. @Michael Holborn, it may be helpful if you switch the question back to its original form, because others may look at this question and be very confused